# Is this question about Percy Shelley’s adulation for poetry now clear enough to be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-votes

I edited this question: [Isn't Percy Shelley’s adulation for poetry bombastically platitudinous and vapid?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3535/175) It should now be clearer; does it still deserve to be closed?

Comment: What changes have you made? Why is the question clearer? Are there other changes you could make to improve the question?

Comment: @Hamlet I'm not sure why the answers to your questions aren't already self-evident? Somehow, I don't feel as if they need be explicitly answered.

Comment: It's obvious to me because I left a bunch of comments on that question. But it wouldn't be obvious to someone who was browsing meta but who hadn't taken a look at the main site question.

Answer (score 3):

From the [help centre](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

I feel that with its current title, "*Isn't Percy Shelley’s adulation for poetry bombastically platitudinous and vapid?*", your question falls under the last of these categories. "[B]ombastically platitudinous and vapid" sounds like a fairly ranty description, and you're seeking to find out whether other people agree with it. The body of your question doesn't suffer from this problem though; a better title would be e.g. "**Is Percy Shelley’s adulation for poetry really justified?**"

However ... I'm not really sure that that's the only problem with this question. I [voted to leave closed](https://literature.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1866) not so much because of the title as because I think the underlying unranty question is primarily opinion-based. It comes down to "*Shelley thinks poetry was great because XYZ; was he right?*" Whether poetry is great, or just as good as a bunch of other kinds of art, is (IMO) a question which should fall below this site's [bar for "primarily opinion-based"-ness](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/844/17).

Ideally the question should have its title edited and then get reopened and closed as POB instead. But the choice of close reason is just housekeeping, and unless it gets reopened and upvoted, it's not going to get much more visibility and will end up automatically deleted by the system. So I think that **your question as it stands should remain closed**. Sorry.

It's possible that with some more edits you *might* be able to make it reopenable. But at the moment I don't have any concrete suggestions for that. Maybe focus more on Shelley and less on the actual merits of poetry?

Comment: Authors and critics spend a lot of time talking about the merits of various mediums/genres. There should be a way for this site to participate in that conversation. I do agree that this question does not represent a good way for us to participate in the conversation. But I can think of a bunch of questions that would lead to constructive conversations. Perhaps a better formatted, quotes from Shelly's original text and not a summary, "why does Shelly say [this particular thing]" about poetry question would work well.

Comment: We really shouldn't be laying out a test for these sorts of questions at this point. We've only received one question, so we don't really have a good idea of what works and what doesn't. At this point we're making up a rule on the basis of some vague hand-waving rather than actual evidence.

Comment: @Hamlet Well, just because authors and critics spend a lot of time talking about something, doesn't mean it can fit well into the framework of a Stack Exchange question :-) But I'm not trying to make any kind of general assertion here about a class of questions, just saying that *this particular question* (as it stands, or with the title fixed but without further edits) falls below the POB line. Does it sound like I'm proposing a "test for these sorts of questions"?

Comment: Thanks. I agree with your 1st paragraph, and edited my post. But asserting my question as 'opinion-based' doesn't appear convincing for a website for literature, which is inherently opinion-based?

Comment: @Canada The bar for what counts as POB is lower on this site than some others, but it still exists: [there are questions about literature which would be too opinion-based to work as SE questions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/844/17).

Comment: @Randal'Thor But my question wouldn't fall below the bar?

Comment: @Canada Well, as I said, _I_ think it does fall below the bar. But I'm just one user. If you can find five users who agree with you that it's above the bar, then the question might be able to get reopened.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor But why do you think so?